# How can I access a custom angular dart component from within a different component that uses it?

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-html

Is there a way to access a component used in a different component's dart file?

Component1.dart

```
@Component(
    selector: 'comp1',
    templateUrl: 'packages/comp1_package/Component1.html',
    cssUrl: 'packages/comp1_package/Component1.css',
    useShadowDom: false)
class Component1 {
  Component1 get comp1ctrl => this;

  Component1()  {

  }

  void testing() {
      // WANT TO CALL COMP2 printTest HERE
  }
}
```

Component1.html

```
<div id="mainTab" class="maincontainer">
    <comp2></comp2>
</div>
```

Component2.dart

```
@Component(
    selector: 'comp2',
    templateUrl: 'packages/comp2_package/Component2.html',
    cssUrl: 'packages/comp2_package/Component2.css',
    useShadowDom: false)
class Component2 {
  Component2 get comp2ctrl => this;

  Component2()  {

  }

  void printTest() {
      print("PRINTING FROM IN COMP2");
  }
}
```

Component2.html

```
<h3>TEST HEADER</h3>
```

How can I get access to the Component2 object in Component1.dart and be able to call a method in it?  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you starting with Dart and Angular? Why not use Angular2 for Dart?

Comment: Yes, I am already starting with Dart and Angular.  Is it an easy change to update everything to Angular2?

Comment: No update to Angular2 won't be too easy. Angular.dart is quite stale (about 1,5 years). All effort goes into Angular2.

Comment: So without updating to Angular 2, is there a way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. It's too long ago that I used Angular.dart. I'm just wondering why now more and more Angular.dart questions appear on SO after such a long time of silence. Some of them turned out to be a misunderstanding about what Angular.dart is related to Angular2 for Dart. Therefore I figured I just ask.